Start-ThreadJob not executing in ps1 file when executed in System.Management.Automation.PowerShell Class
I have a powershell script that i am executing via System.Management.Automation.Powershell.Invoke.  in the script i have Start-ThreadJob... | Wait-Job...
Running the script on the command line using pwsh.exe does exactly what i need it it do... the job starts and the Wait-Job causes the script to pause execution until the job is done before it moves on.
When I execute this same ps1 file using System.Management.Automation.Powershell.Invoke method, the Start-Thread Job command does not seem to be getting fired.  The script just continues on and this is causing the rest of my script do not do anything else as it relies on the job I intend to start.
Since I know running the powershell command with pwsh on the command line works, I know my PowerShell logic is correct.
I also tested putting a Start-Sleep in my code  and execute it through .Invoke and the script respected pause before returning back to my .net logic. I have tried Start-ThreadJob and Start-Job as well, neither seem to execute as expected.  And I am coming up very short with any research.
I am excepting my .net client to allow the script to execute as designed.  It should allow the PowerShell script to pause execution while a job is started and flagged as "Completed". I can get the expected behavior if I run pswh as a process in dotnet and pass the arguments that way but I feel it should work though the api also.
The following code is an example of what seems to not be working:
$codeBlock = [scriptblock]::Create("kubectl wait --timeout=-1s --for=condition=Failed job/$batchStatus -n $namespace")
$stj = Start-ThreadJob -Name "$batchStatus-failed" -ScriptBlock $codeBlock 
"WaitFailed job state after apply: $($stj.Name)"
wait-Job -Id $stj | Out-Null

the "wait failed..." print out never shows the $stj.Name value, i assume that is because the $stj never gets fired
The PowerShell logic is in a file called Execute.ps1
this is my C# logic to execute Execute.ps1
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell ps = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\powershell\execute.ps1"));
var t = ps.Invoke();

I would think the ps.Invoke() would execute the function and wait for the powershell to be complete before it returns... the $codeBlock in the PowerShell should cause the script to process and wait on that job to complete.  Again this works perfectly fine when I execute the PowerShell command on the pwsh command line, it is only when I execute it through System.Management.Automation.PowerShell I see this behavior

What version of System.Management.Automation.dll are you referencing in the C# project, what runtime framework version are you targeting, and have you tried inspecting ps.HadErrors/ps.Streams.Error after ps.Invoke() returns?

I am running 7.4.3 of the System.Management.Automation.dll The errors I am seeing say "The term 'Start-ThreadJob' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
But Start-ThreadJob is Powershell 7 cmdlet valid as i can run this same script in a pwsh.exe command line.  Does System.Manament.Automation not use what's available to pwsh?

The PowerShell SDK does not come with the external modules that a stand-alone PowerShell installation comes bundled with; notably this means that the ThreadJob module is not available by default, although it situationally may be discoverable via a stand-alone PowerShell installation - but you cannot rely on that; see this answer for background information.
You have two solution options:

Design-time solution: You can manually bundle the module with your application (I think there are no licensing concerns, but you should  check):

Place a copy of the module in the Modules subfolder of your application executable, alongside the built-in modules (such as Microsoft.PowerShell.Management).
For instance, in a debug build on Windows with .NET 8, this folder is ./bin/Debug/net8/runtimes/win/lib/net8.0/Modules

This answer offers an automated way to do this, via build tooling (using the nuget.config and  *.csproj files).



Runtime solution: You can download the module on demand at runtime (needless to see, you'll need an internet connection at runtime):

See the bottom section of this answer for PowerShell code that does that, which you could run via .AddScript()
Note that the linked code cannot make use of Save-Module or Save-PSResource, because the modules containing these commands, PowerShellGet and Microsoft.PowerShell.PSResourceGet, are also not available by default in an SDK project.



